# meta box on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Okay I have look on the site and need more help! I am adding Learndash to my site and need a meta box to show on their custom post type pages.

Here is the meta box code I have which works fine for just normal posts;

```
    // META

$prefix = 'dbt_';
$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'my-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Post Customization',
    'page' =>  'post', 
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Post Color',
            'id' => $prefix . 'color',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array('orange', 'pink', 'green', 'purple')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Image URL',
            'desc' => 'Optional',
            'id' => $prefix . 'img-url',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std'  => 'Image'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Video URL',
            'desc' => 'Optional',
            'id' => $prefix . 'video-url',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std'  => 'Video'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Link URL',
            'desc' => 'Optional',
            'id' => $prefix . 'link-url',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std'  => 'Link'
        ),
     )
);

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');
```

Now how do I get it to show on all the following post types;

sfwd-courses
sfwd-lessons
sfwd-topics
...

Replacing `'page' =>  'post',`  with `'page' =>  'sfwd-courses',` shows the meta box on the courses page but not normal posts.

I thought the following should work but does not...

`'page' =>  'post', 'sfwd-courses', 'sfwd-lessons', 'sfwd-topics',`

Please help...

Comment: This isn't default WordPress meta box code... it looks like it is supposed to use the Meta Box plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add your post types in an array. So your code should look like this

```
'pages' => array('post', 'sfwd-courses', 'sfwd-lessons', 'sfwd-topics'),
```

You should also have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html) that I find helpful as well

Comment: Nothing! The box does not show anywhere with this code?

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial I've included